# How to disable autocompleting quotations in Netbeans 8

Tags: double, netbeans-8, quoting

How can I disable the double quoting feature in Netbeans 8?

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, actually it works, `Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion`, but `Closing Brackets` option has nothing to do with it, instead you should select specific language (my case is `PHP`) and uncheck `Use Smart Quotes...`.

That exactly does the job and you also keep auto brackets. There is no such option in "All languages" so it's easy to miss.

Comment: Works on the newest NetBeans as well. I guess I mistook "brackets" and "quotes".

Answer (score 0):

Tools => Options => Editor => Code Completion => uncheck Insert Closing Brackets Automatically.

BEWARE!

Even if you have selected ALL LANGUAGES in the select box, unchecking this option might NOT work for all, so to be safe, select PHP (for example) in the Select box and uncheck the same checkbox for PHP.